# XSLT string subsitutions

Tags: string, xslt

In XSLT 2.0, is there an easy way to replace named placeholders in a string?

I'm thinking of something like Python's string.Template, where you can do this:

```
d = dict(name='Joe', age='50')
print Template("My name is $name and my age is $age").substitute(d)
```

The point is to externalize the string, so it can be easily changed. The only way I've found so far is to use a named xsl:template with parameters, but this is pretty verbose. Is there an easier way?

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  Do you want an automated mechanism that will look for tokens in the form of, say $name, lookup "name" in a table of substitution values and replace $name with the value?  In specific text nodes? Globally?

Comment: I'm looking for something that I can call, passing it a specific string and a set of parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing something like this:

```
<!-- Reusable template to perform substitutions on a string -->
<xsl:template name="substitutions">
    <!-- "string" is a string with placeholders surrounded by {} -->
    <xsl:param name="string" />
    <!-- "subs" is a list of nodes whose "key" attributes are the placeholders -->
    <xsl:param name="subs" />
    <xsl:analyze-string select="$string" regex="\{{(.*?)\}}">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:value-of select="$subs/sub[@key=regex-group(1)]" />
        </xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Example use of template -->
<xsl:variable name="nameStr">My name is {name} and my age is {age}</xsl:variable>
<xsl:call-template name="substitutions">
    <xsl:with-param name="string" select="$nameStr" />
    <xsl:with-param name="subs">
        <sub key="name">Joe</sub>
        <sub key="age">50</sub>
    </xsl:with-param>
</xsl:call-template>
```

I had to use attributes for the substitution names, rather than just passing nodes with different names (e.g. <name>Joe</name>). XPath (or at least Saxon, the processor I'm using) doesn't seem to allow dynamic expressions like "$subs/regex-group(1)". But it does allow "$subs/sub[@key=regex-group(1)]".

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a high-level feature on the order of Python string templates, but you could do something similar using xsl:analyze-string, which will let you process a regex analysis of a string a piece at a time.  If you wanted the replacments to be table-driven you could set up an xsl:key to store the mapping, and write an xsl:function to perform the replacement on an arbitrary string.

Not the easiest thing in the world, but certainly doable and reusable later if done correctly.

Comment: Good idea to use analyze-string -- see my solution, posted as a separate answer.